# How to get a JSON object back from a Jenkins build request

Tags: json, bash, build, jenkins

Similar to how `http://localhost/jenkins/job/job_name/25/api/json` would return a `JSON` object with the details of build 26, is there a way to get a similar object when first initiating the job, i.e., before you know what the build number is?

I noticed the output from a `curl` post request to the build url returns `html` that includes a build number; however, I would prefer not to have to parse this in favor of having a `JSON` object with the build number in it. Currently, I am using:

```
curl -v --data "param1=value&param2=value" \
http://localhost/jenkins/job/job_name/buildWithParameters
```

which initiates the job fine and outputs a bunch of `html`. Is there a way to start this job and receive a `JSON` object with the build number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you query `http://localhost/jenkins/job/job_name/api/json` you can fetch the `nextBuildNumber` field anytime that will give you the next build number.

When you trigger a build, you can rest assured the build will get exactly this number.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. One thing though, do you know if there is anyway to account for queued up builds? If build 37 is in progress now and I post a second build, the `nextBuildNumber` still returns 38 even though 38 is taken by the queued build. It only updates to 39 once the queued build has started. I guess I could account for this on my end some how.

Comment: Not on top of my head. You can check for `queueItem` as well, but that doesn't have build numbers in it.. Not sure right now, need to run a few tests.

Comment: If you run `curl .../job_name/api/json | python -mjson.tool` you can get a readabale json output by the way.

Answer (score 6):

The nextBuildNumber may not be the correct build number in all cases. If you have triggered two different builds of the same Job, we don't know which one got triggered first. There is a race condition here. Checking the build queue may not give the correct build number either.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the build has been triggered, you can get its URL back from:

```
http://localhost/jenkins/job/job_name/api/json?tree=lastBuild[url]
```

This will return the running build if there is one, or the latest completed build otherwise.  You can then add "/api/json" to that URL to get your build's JSON object.

Comment: This will not return anything if the build is blocked and is waiting for a start. Or, let's say it will return last build, but it's not the one OP wants :)

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I needed a JSONP data type to go through. What I did is get the raw object of my particular job from Jenkins so that then I can manipulate it as necessary.

Request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<jenkins server>/job/<job name>/api/json?jsonp=?",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: success
});
```

Success call:

```
var success = function(json) {

 console.log('Raw JSON object for this job:');
 console.log(json);    
}
```

Then, get the info you need, such as:

```
console.log(json.lastCompletedBuild.number);
console.log(json.lastBuild.url);
```